# A well-defined map from rational numbers to integers

Tags: functions, integers, rational-numbers

I am trying to come up with a well-defined map from $\mathbb{Q}$$\to$ $\mathbb{Z}$

i.e. find a map $f$ such that it maps $\frac{a}{b}$ $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{Q}$ to an integer in $\mathbb{Z}$. I tried a couple of things, and unfortunately, they did not work.

The one that I recently came up with is the given map:

$f$($\frac{a}{b}$)= $\frac{a+b}{gcd(a,b)}$

However, I just do not see how I can prove that this is indeed a well-defined map. All I am doing at this stage is randomly plugging numbers to see if this works.

Is this map well-defined? If yes, can someone help me prove it? If not, is there a well-defined map from 
$\mathbb{Q}$$\to$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $?$

Comment: How about $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\Bbb Q$? Or is there something else you want from your map?

Comment: Thought about it, but it seems too trivial to me. I am absolutely not saying that it cannot work, but I wanted to play with something non-trivial.

Comment: Can you at least decide what to you is trivial, and what isn't?

Comment: $f(\frac{5}{3})=\frac{5+3}{\gcd(5,3)}=f(\frac{1}{7})=\frac{1+7}{\gcd(1,7)}=8$. What do you want exactly?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas you just took a random rational number and found the functional value. I wanted to prove that the mapping I came up with is "well-defined."

Comment: The map $f(x)=0$ is certainly well defined. So if it doesn't count as an answer you need to edit the question to explain what you really want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your map is well-defined. Suppose that $\frac ab=\frac cd$. Let $m=\frac a{\gcd(a,b)}$ and let $n=\frac b{\gcd(a,b)}$. Then there are integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $a=\alpha m$, $b=\alpha n$, $c=\beta m$, and $d=\beta n$. Then$$\frac{a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}=\frac{\alpha m+\alpha n}{\gcd(\alpha m,\alpha n)}=\frac{m+n}{\gcd(m,n)}$$and$$\frac{c+d}{\gcd(c,d)}=\frac{\beta m+\beta n}{\gcd(\beta m,\beta n)}=\frac{m+n}{\gcd(m,n)}.$$So$$\frac{a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}=\frac{c+d}{\gcd(c,d)}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sets are countably infinite therefore such a mapping definately exists.
One of many possible maps is as follows.
Let's represent the rational numbers as $$ s\frac{p}{q} $$ p,q belong to natural numbers and the GCD of p and q is 1 and s belongs to set {1,-1}.
Then we define $$ f: Q\rightarrow Z    $$
$$f(s\frac{p}{q})=s2^p3^q$$
Done!

Comment: How is this mapping well defined?
For instance, if I have let's say s = 1, p = 1, and q = 2, then I have $\frac{1}{2}$ and if I take another rational number for which s = 1, p = 2, and q = 4 then I have $\frac{2}{4}$. And we know that the two rational numbers are equal. But if I know plug them in the map, the value I get are not equal, and hence the map is not "well-defined."

Comment: What do you mean by "well defined"?

Comment: Should be well defined now.

Comment: A correspondence $f$: $A$ $\to$ $B$ is called well-defined if for all a,b $\in$ A such that if a = b then f(a) = f(b).

Comment: Still well defined. Because we took the GCD of p and q to be 1.